# Azure Account-Level SAS Token: Possible to Have a Policy?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I found how to create an Azure account-level SAS token with PowerShell. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestorageaccountsastoken?view=azurermps-5.2.0) However, the cmdlet `New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken` does not appear to accept a `-Policy` parameter.

Does this mean that there cannot be a SAS policy on an account-level SAS token? An implication would be that if the token were compromised, one could not just remove the policy but would have to change the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Stored access policies are currently not supported for account SAS.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/establishing-a-stored-access-policy).

Stored access policies are only available for:

- Blob containers
- File shares
- Queues
- Tables

Thus you won't find it on the account level.